# Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'- AMPLIFY REACTJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, cors

I am trying to upload a file from my frontend to S3 bucket by fetching URL from my server to the frontend and then putting the file in the bucket, but I keep getting `Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`. My backend and frontend are hosted using Amplify. Below are the details:

FRONTEND

```
              axios
                .get('<BACKEND_URL>/s3Url')
                .then((res) => {
                  const { url } = res.data;

                  axios.put(url, e.target.files[0], {
                    headers: {
                      'Content-Type': e.target.files[0].type,
                    },
                  })
                  .then(alert('File Uploaded Successfully'))
                  .catch((err) => alert('Error in uploading file'))
                  ;
                })
                .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Here I am getting the error while calling the outer get request.

BACKEND:

```
import express from 'express'
import { generateUploadURL } from './s3.js'
import cors from "cors"

const app = express()

app.use(cors());
const corsOptions ={ 
  credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
  optionSuccessStatus:200
}

app.get('/s3Url', async (req, res) => {
  const url = await generateUploadURL()
  res.send({url})
})

app.listen(8080, () => console.log("listening on port 8080"))
```

`generateUploadURL()` brings the URL necessary for uploading the The code works fine locally but hosted backend is giving me the above error.

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Where this corsOptions is used?

Comment: I was just testing out some configurations

Comment: @CodeThing can you help me find the error?

Comment: I believe you need to add your frontend url in the origin option. You can find this configuration in the cors docs in npmjs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: app.use(cors({
  origin: ['https://main.d**s****rldeq.amplifyapp.com','http://localhost:3000'],
  methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
}));
I have added it to the cors options but still facing the same issue @CodeThing

Comment: Try giving full url with http:// or https://

Comment: I have given the full url but after posting it here it is getting truncated. In my code I have the full URL @CodeThing